# Android Studio ListView Checkbox Save

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

Ive looked at a few other questions on stackoverflow about this questions however I am not able to implement this into my code as I have done things a bit differently I believe. I am still learning Android Studio so please bear with me for any stupidity.

I'm looking to create check boxes on the right side of the listview I currently have that when checked will stay in that state when the user loads the application back in.

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Which Will Be Next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#f1b75a"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"  />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/results_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Code:

```
public class .... extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_flavour);

    ListView resultListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_listview);

    HashMap<String, String> nameAddress = new HashMap<>();
    nameAddress.put("exmp ", "Locate");


    List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"First Address", "Second Address"},new int[]{R.id.tv1, R.id.tv3});

    Iterator it  = nameAddress.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair  = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Address", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second Address", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultsMap);

    }

    resultListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


}
```

List Items.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffa200"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    />
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: So actually what u want to do?

Comment: @LokeshDesai I would like to add a checkbox to each item of the listview, if they click it the state is saved for next time they log in

Comment: Simple just use share preferance for storing state of selected checkbox

Comment: @LokeshDesai Would you mind helping me on how to do this? Im not sure where to start, for first getting the checkboxes to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the you can use Recyclerview instead listview, Try this way

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter extends
  RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 private List<Student> stList;

 public CardViewDataAdapter(List<Student> students) {
  this.stList = students;

 }

 // Create new views
 @Override
 public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
   int viewType) {
  // create a new view
  View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
    R.layout.cardview_row, null);

  // create ViewHolder

  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

  return viewHolder;
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

  final int pos = position;

  viewHolder.tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getName());

  viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(stList.get(position).getEmailId());

  viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isSelected());

  viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));


  viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    Student contact = (Student) cb.getTag();

    contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
    stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

    Toast.makeText(
      v.getContext(),
      "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
        + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });

 }

 // Return the size arraylist
 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
  return stList.size();
 }

 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public TextView tvName;
  public TextView tvEmailId;

  public CheckBox chkSelected;

  public Student singlestudent;

  public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
   super(itemLayoutView);

   tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

   tvEmailId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
   chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView
     .findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);

  }

 }

 // method to access in activity after updating selection
 public List<Student> getStudentist() {
  return stList;
 }

}
```

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Comment: Im only understand some of that, and it also looks like it takes a bit more in order to make it work. Im trying to keep it simple, so I can learn the easy ways first, but if I cant find a different way I shall look further into this. Thank you

Comment: Alright I have tried to implement this however still I have no luck, not sure what im doing and getting allot of errors. Is it possible for you to show how you would implement this with the way Ive got it?

Comment: It seems that allot of the code in that blog post is out dated unfortunately :(

Comment: are you using web api for this?

Comment: Im not fully understanding but its an app made within the Android Studio API only using googles API, I copied the code exact from that blogpost changing the package and it still didnt work.

Comment: first of all dont copy code from anywhere,yet if you copy,you must be clear with your requirements. i guess you are using firebase database, first of all create example with static or dummy data,then change it with your database.

Comment: Error:(11, 33) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView

Comment: I have got the checkbox to show and everything now im just trying to save the state so when the person re opens the app they can view the state of the checkedboxes again, I created a new post for this as I thought it would be a bit more efficient for people to answer, however I do thank you for your help and commitment in helping me :)